# Qt C++ I want to pass data with MainWindow to item window, but I get errorr: LNK2019

Tags: c++, qt

I want to pass data with MainWindow to item window, but I get error:

> moc_form.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public:
>   void __cdecl Form::getItemID(class QString)"
>   (?getItemID@Form@@QEAAXVQString@@@Z) referenced in function "private:
>   static void __cdecl Form::qt_static_metacall(class QObject *,enum
>   QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)"
>   (?qt_static_metacall@Form@@CAXPEAVQObject@@W4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)

MainWindow.h

```
signals:
    void sendData(QString str);
private slots:
    void on_tableView_doubleClicked(const QModelIndex &index);

private:
    DialogItem *myform;
```

MainWindow.cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{

    myform = new DialogItem();
    connect(this, SIGNAL(sendData(QString)), myform, SLOT(getItemID(QString)));
}

void MainWindow::on_tableView_doubleClicked(const QModelIndex &index)
{
 //   int row = index.row();
    QModelIndex mi = table->currentIndex() ;
    QString selectedItemName = table->model()->data(mi).toString();
//    QString str = index.data().toString();


    table->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
    QModelIndex currentDiscount  = ui->tableView->currentIndex();
    emit sendData(table->model()->data(table->model()->index(currentDiscount.row(),1),0));
    qDebug() << table->model()->data(table->model()->index(currentDiscount.row(),1),0);

    qDebug() << table->model()->index( table->currentIndex().row(), 0 ).data().toInt();

    DialogItem *dialog = new DialogItem;
    dialog->show();
}
```

dialogItem.h

```
public slots:
    void DescriptionItem();
    vector<QString> getItemID(QString partNumber);
```

dialogItem.cpp

```
vector<QString> DialogItem::getItemID(QString partNumber);
{
    vector<QString> descriptionItem;

    QSqlQuery query;
    QString sstr = "SELECT * FROM \"" + tableName + "\" WHERE \"" + Part Number + "\" = \'" + partNumber + "\'"
    query.exec(sstr);

    while (query.next())
    {
        QString value = query.value(0).toString();
        tableNames.push_back(value);
    }

    return descriptionItem;
}
```

Comment: You're showing all the code that's not relevant to the error. The linker complains that you didn't implement `void Form::getItemID(QString)`.

Comment: clean your project and build your project again.

Comment: why can't I get the text in a itemDialog form?